# Create a CSV from Ember Data model objects?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, emblem.js

I have a model in Ember with two actions/components associated. The first, `runQuery`, queries the store and retrieves results. The second `downloadCSV` should ideally take the model attributes `headers` and `rows` (generated and formatted from [PapaParse](http://papaparse.com/)) and export it as a csv when a button is clicked.

```
runQuery(id, uid) {
  const queryData = {id, uid};

  this.store.find('queryResult', queryData).then( results => {
    let result = results.toArray().get(0);
    this.set('controller.model.result', result);
    this.set('controller.model.headers', results.content[0]._data.headers);
    this.set('controller.model.rows', results.content[0]._data.rows);

  });
},

downloadCSV(headers, rows) {
  exportCSV(headers, rows)
}
```

I'm using an emblem template to pass the csvData back to the download CSV method:

```
csv-data action="downloadCSV" headers=model.headers rows=model.rows
```

But when I try to run the method, the headers and rows always undefined despite being accessible in the template. (I can see it on the page with `{{model.headers}}`/ `{{model.rows}}` and iterate over them to display a table using emblem's `each` method)

I see that Ember Data models do not support complex object types. Is there a way I can make the header and row objects globally accessible after they are generated so the download data method can properly consume them?

Comment: Do you have the properties `headers` and `rows` defined on your model as an `attr()`?

Comment: Yes. I'll specify in the question.

Comment: I'm not familiar with emblem syntax, is there a specific reason you are using it instead of the recommended HTMLBars that are shipped with ember? Can you explain what this emblem snippet is supposed to do? Are you defining a component called `csv-data` and passing parameters: string `action` and arrays `headers` and `rows` to it? Regardless, at which point are you passing the arguments `headers` and `rows` into the action `downloadCSV` and where are you calling this action?